# How do I force subprocess.call or os.system to run in bash, instead of dash?

Tags: bash, python-3.x, terminal, subprocess, dash-shell

Okay, so I've been struggling with this one for awhile. I'm trying to create a python3 script that automatically uploads a file to a server. In the commandline, the following command works like a charm:

```
sftp -i key.pem -P 3912 admin@myServerIP:home/files/ <<< $"put test.txt"
```

But, when I try to run that command in my python script (either through `os.system('command')` or `subprocess.call('command')`) I keep getting the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

After doing some research, I believe I found that I need to run the command in /bin/bash, instead of the default dash, but I've tried everything, and connot for the life of me figure out how to do that! I hope this is a simple, stupid fix, so I can be on my way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your command with this one:

```
/bin/bash -c 'sftp -i key.pem -P 3912 admin@myServerIP:home/files/ <<< $"put test.txt"'
```

which should work fine even in Dash. :-)

(Incidentally, I think you meant to write `"put test.txt"` instead of `$"put test.txt"`. But that's neither here nor there.)

---

**Edited to add:** I should mention that your specific example is easy to rewrite in a Dash-compatible way:

```
echo "put test.txt" | sftp -i key.pem -P 3912 admin@myServerIP:home/files/
```

which may make more sense in this case. But you will very likely find the `bash -c ...` approach useful for other things in the future.